# phpmyadmin wont open project index.php - must manually type url

Tags: url, phpmyadmin

I just updated wampserver/phpmyadmin/php/apache from last years version on all my  machines and I got everything running fine except when I open a project from localhost, (click a folder), it no longer auto loads the folders index.php or even display the contents of the folder because the path is wrong in the url. Instead of localhost/foldername/index.php it just goes to httpp://foldername, which fails.

I'm guessing this is a configuration issue but I'm not sure where to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by the DirectoryIndex directive of Apache. You need to add index.php to it (probably it only contains index.html). Here is an example of where you can change this: c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.4\conf\httpd.conf.